# Converting complex-exponential summation to Fresnel integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

I have a summation
$$S = \sum_{n=0}^N e^{-jn^2a}, \ a\ne 0, \ n\in\{0,1,\cdots,N\}$$
and it can be approximated by
$$S\approx I = \int_{n=0}^N e^{-jn^2a}dn$$
when $N$ is sufficiently large. Furthermore, the integral $I$ can be expressed by the Fresnel integrals:
$$I =\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{n=0}^{N\sqrt{a}}e^{-jn^2}dn = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int_{n=0}^{N\sqrt{a}}\{\cos(n^2)-j\sin(n^2)\}dn = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\left(C(N\sqrt{a}) - jS(N\sqrt{a})\right)$$
where $C(x)$ and $S(x)$ are, respectively, defined by
$$C(x) = \int_{0}^x\sin(x^2)dx, \ \ 
S(x) = \int_{0}^x\cos(x^2)dx$$

However, the above derivation seems not correct. This is because $S$ has periodicity while $I$ not. As I can imagine, teh relationship between $\int_{n=0}^N e^{-jn^2a}dn$ and $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{n=0}^{N\sqrt{a}}e^{-jn^2}dn$ does not always hold. So how to formulate the relationship between these two terms.

Comment: Assuming $j=i=\sqrt{-1}$ then $$\int\limits_0^N e^{-i a n^2} \, dn=-\frac{(-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{\pi }\, \text{erf}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1} \sqrt{a}\, N\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(C\left(\sqrt{a}\, N \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)-i S\left(\sqrt{a}\, N \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{a}}.$$

Comment: Thanks. My major concern is the relationship between $S$ and $I$. I have added the definition of the Fresnel integrals. I have awared that the fresnel integrals in your answer is the one with $(\pi/2)x^2 $ as the argument.

Comment: The integral $$\int\limits_0^K e^{-i a n^2} \, dn=\frac{1}{\sqrt{i a}} \int\limits_0^{\sqrt{i a}\, K} e^{-t^2} \, dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\, \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{i a}\, K\right)}{2 \sqrt{i a}}\tag{1}$$ follows from the definition $$\text{erf}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int\limits_0^z e^{-t^2} \, dt\tag{2}$$ so perhaps your assumption about the integral $$S\approx I=\int\limits_0^N e^{-i n^2 a}\, dn\tag{3}$$ approximating the summation $$S=\sum\limits_{n=0}^N e^{-i n^2 a}\tag{4}$$ is incorrect. What is the basis for your assumption?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-i a n^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\vartheta_3\left(0,e^{-i a}\right)\right)\tag{5}$$ doesn't converge for $a\in\mathbb{R}$. I believe it only converges for $\Im(a)<0$.

Comment: Maybe the assumption $S \approx I$ is not correct. I have checked the theta function, which is defined as $$\vartheta (z;\tau) = \sum_{n = - \infty}^\infty \exp(\pi i n^2 \tau + 2\pi i n z)$$ and its integral representations is $$-i\int_{i-\infty}^{i + \infty} e^{i \pi \tau u^2}\frac{cos(2\pi u z + \pi u)}{sin(\pi u)}du$$

Comment: I might have found the problem.  $$S = \sum_{n=0}^N e^{-jn^2a}, \ a\ne 0, \ n\in\{0,1,\cdots,N\}$$  can be considered as generalized quadratic Gaussian sums, and its value depends only on $\mod(-a(N-1),N-1)$, see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum#Definition). On the other hand, $I$, which is expressed by the Fresnel integrals, depends on $a$.